# how to use a controller's action in all controllers

Tags: php, view, yii, widget, action

I have an action that renders `search` view to do search as the above search bar in this website, so its should be shown in every view.

I don't know what is the mechanism to do it. for example if I make the search action as a widget this will not be fine, because the results of search will be shown in the same position of the search widget ( at the top of website).

so, how I can make a search action that should be shown in every view in the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resue same search function in everywhere, you need to create a widget.
I have explained briefly in [How a widget works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579932/how-to-run-yii-widget-when-button-clicked?answertab=active#tab-top), then you can attach it in every view that you want.

If you don't have any idea to begin, check this out: [Yii ESearch](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/esearch/)

Here are some references that would be useful:

[how-to-use-a-widget-as-an-action-provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/146/how-to-use-a-widget-as-an-action-provider)

[actions-code-reuse-with-caction/](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/170/actions-code-reuse-with-caction/)

[Yii Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget)

Comment: if I used widget, the results will appear in the position that where I used the search widget, which is the top of website.

Comment: That situation is a must have flexibility to handle. You can pass  into your search widget a selector (such as id) of html tag (such div) where you would like to display search result, every times search button is clicked, it will request by ajax, fetch the search result and put them all into the passed selector.

Comment: I want to put the results in a page called results, is it possible to posting them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add something to every view then you should add it to the layout. By the sounds of it you don't need to use a widget at all, although it would probably help with code maintainability.

You never mentioned a requirement for ajax so keep it simple and don't use it. When someone enters a search and clicks submit (or presses return) then the form submits to the SearchController. This way there is no need to have a search action in each controller.

If you particularly want the same action in every controller then create a Controller base class with that function in it and inherit from it to create all your other controllers.